# Strategies for mixing cloud/local usage?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'm trying to see if it's worth moving partially to cloud (ie, do some work in browser when I'm on a laptop, but the rest in local Mathematica when I'm on a more powerful desktop machine), and there seem to be some snags in local Mathematica integration with cloud files. I'm wondering if people have some common strategies for this kind of mixed usage.

In particular

1. "Cloud Browser->Open File in Mathematica", will save a copy of file rather than linked cloud file
2. Saving cloud file in Mathematica prompts each time if I want to overwrite, whereas Cloud browser saves without such prompt.
3. To see changes in Cloud browser that were done by using Mathematica, I have to close and reopen the file in cloud browser.
4. To see changes in Mathematica that were done in Cloud Browser, I have to close the file and re-open it using File/Open From Cloud

Is it just better to only edit file either in one or the other?

Comment: I tend to only *work* locally but deploy / mirror in the cloud. The desktop interface still far outstrips the cloud one, but the functionality provided makes it easy to make palettes and scripts to move notebooks / packages / whatever through the cloud or host local sites and things there.